# Change password of PhpMyAdmin on localhost

Tags: mysql, login, password

I have upgraded Ubuntu 9.10 to Ubuntu 10.10 but I cannot access PhpMyAdmin. How can I change the username and password for PhpMyAdmin? I urgently need to access PhpMyaAmin because my database is there. I need to upload the database onto my server but I can't access it.

The error message shown is `#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server`.

Answer (score 3):

The password for phpMyAdmin is your mysql admin username and password.  There are not separate login details for phpMyAdmin itself.

Answer (score 2):

In Command line:>

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -p 'oldpassword' password newpass
```